# The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip' does not exist

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I just cloned a project and it opened in Android Studio. This Error was given:
The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip' does not exist.

How can i fix this?

Comment: You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on Stack Overflow. But to do so, you should ask the question as a proper question (see [ask]) - and then, separately, provide your answer as an actual answer (not as part of the question).

Comment: Browse the [help] for more guidance on asking and answering.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptor before using a tag on your post.

Comment: Im sorry im new here. thanks for the information. im doing it insch

Comment: You need to re-write the question, so that it is an actual Stack Overflow question (not a question containing an answer). I refer you again to [ask] for more details. (Also, apologies, but what does "insch" mean?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must run Android Studio as an Administrator and everthing is solved.